# Want to move an object from 1st place to 2nd and then 1st again using translate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity. I want to move an object from one place to another and then back to the 1st place again automatically. Is there any way to do that? Here's my code to move the object, but it's going infinity and beyond!

```
float speedX = 1; float speedY = 0; float speedZ = 0;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
     transform.Translate (new Vector3 (speedX, speedY, speedZ) * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you only translated the object in the same direction without any restriction to stop. One way of doing that can be using Lerp to interpolate the position values from one point to another.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

The code below moves a gameObject from p1 to p2 and then returned to p1;

```
public Transform p1, p2;
public float speed = 1.0f;
private float startTime;
private float journeyLength;
bool isMovingForward = true;
float threshold = 0.001f;

void Start () {
    startTime = Time.time;
    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(p1.position, p2.position);
}

void Update () {
    if (isMovingForward && Mathf.Abs((transform.position - p2.position).sqrMagnitude) < (threshold * threshold)){
        isMovingForward = false;
        startTime = Time.time;
    }
    float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
    float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

    if (isMovingForward)
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(p1.position, p2.position, fracJourney);
    else
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(p2.position, p1.position, fracJourney);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,thats exactly what i was looking for.